Unable to setup FTP in IIS due to missing IIS Manager Users feature
I followed the steps to setup my FTP server. But what I couldn't find is - there is no management feature under management due to which I am unable to configure the users. Can you help me why I cannot see the management users feature, any missing permission?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7
Under Management service, I only see 3 features:
Configuration Editor
Feature Delegation
Shared Configuration
There should be IIS Manager Users feature which is missing.

do you have authentication types installed (basic, digest, ..., etc)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you install the IIS Role Service "Management Service"?
